# How do you pass state variables between two separate functional components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
 function passVar(){

 const [pass1,setPass1]=useState("")
 const [pass2,setPass2]=useState("")
 const [pass3,setPass3]=useState("")


  return(
  //gets values of these "pass" variables from a text input inside this return function
  );
```

}

```
function recieveVar(){

 const [pass4,setPass4]=useState("")
 const [pass5,setPass5]=useState("")


const computeVar = ()=>{


exampleFunction(
pass1,
pass2,
pass3,
pass4,
pass5

)

}

  return(
        //gets values of these "pass" variables from a text input inside this return function



  );

 }



}
```

I don't know react native that well and I need help with the code writing itself. I tried using useContext() but it was written in react and I'm a beginner so I don't really understand how to implement it. Also, there are no parent functions for this piece of code and both functions are in the same file. I need someway to first pass the state variables from the "passVar" function into the "recieveVar" function. I made a parent function called "parent" that encompasses both functions and declared the state variables inside the parent function but there was a problem because Stack Navigator said that it couldn't find the recieveVar and  passVar function since they were child components

Comment: Its hard to imagine your setup because you didn’t provide the information regarding your setup of StackNavigation and “parent” component. Basically to share state you can use redux, contextAPI or sent parameters in navigate.

Comment: @SaachiTech, those were just the things I troubleshooted and it didn't work so it's not a part of my actual code. I just want to share the state between the two functions, but I don't know how to actually code using redux/contextAPI and I don't really understand the documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass state variables between two functional components using props. You can declare `state` variable in your `PassVar` like:

```
const [pass1,setPass1]=useState("")
const [pass2,setPass2]=useState("")
const [pass3,setPass3]=useState("")
```

and then pass these to `RecieveVar()` by rendering `receivevar` inside your `Passvar` function and then passing these values as params like:

```
<ReceiveVar pass1={pass1} pass2={pass2} pass3={pass3} />
```

then you can receive these values inside `RecieveVar()` like:

```
RecieveVar(props){
      console.log(props.pass1);
      console.log(props.pass2);
      console.log(props.pass3);
    };
```

If you are not rendering `RecieveVar` inside `PassVar` then you can send these values to `receiveVar` using navigation. Like:

```
navigation.navigate('RecieveVar',{pass1,pass2,pass3});
```

then you can receive these values inside `receiveVar()` as :

```
const ReceiveVar(props){
 const {pass1,pass2,pass3}=props.route.params;
    console.log(pass1);
    console.log(pass2);
    console.log(pass3);
 }
```